# Sorting a dataframe

Tags: r

Working with carData package,dataset - salaries. Question requires to check the yrs.since.phd variable. What is the difference in salary of the professor with the highest (yrs.since.phd) and lowest (yrs.since.phd)?
`x<-salary_data[c("yrs.since.phd","salary")]` gives me the 2 variables but how do I sort them from lowest to highest in order to be able to compare, or shall I use different function?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways for sorting a dataframe, one of which is with `dplyr::arrange`. This orders the rows of the dataframe in the order you assign, e.g.

```
carData::Salaries %>% 
  arrange(rank, yrs.since.phd, salary)
```

Will sort the data after `rank`, then after `yrs.since.phd`, then after `salary`.
However, you also seem interested in comparing these. We can `summarise` the mean salary for professors by the max and min `yrs.since.phd`:

```
carData::Salaries %>%
  filter(rank == "Prof") %>% # Get data for professors only
  filter(yrs.since.phd == max(yrs.since.phd) |
           yrs.since.phd == min(yrs.since.phd)) %>% # Get only max and min values
  group_by(yrs.since.phd) %>% # For each value of yrs.since.phd
  summarise(mean_salary = mean(salary), # Calculate mean salary
            n = n()) # See how many are included in the calculation

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  yrs.since.phd mean_salary     n
*         <int>       <dbl> <int>
1            11      142467     1
2            56      131900     2
```

That is the general gist of it, but you might want to build on this for further analysis.

Comment: @user15675493, if this answered your question please consider accepting it to mark your question as resolved.